# I want to do correlation for many data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, correlation

i have almost 13 files and i want to conduct three types of correlations to it.
all the files have the same content except the values.

for example:

v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  ........... v50

first correclation between v6 and v20
second correlation between v7 and v21
third correlation between  v8 and v22

my data have missing values.

doing it manually for each file will leads to a too long scrip, i want to do a loop function for all the files ( unfortunately im not expert in loop function and i tried so much)   I need help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'd1', 'd2', ...'d13' are the datasets and the columns are the in the same order, we can place the dataset in a `list` and get the `cor` for the specified columns.  There are options in `?cor` to compute the covariances in the presence of missing values.  Here, I used `na.or.complete`.  We can change it according to the need.

```
lapply(mget(paste0('d', 1:13)), function(x) 
      diag(cor(x[,6:8], x[,20:22], use='na.or.complete')))
```

It may be better to read the files into a `list` directly than creating individual `data.frame` objects in the global environment.  Assuming that the files are all in the working directory.

```
files <- list.files(pattern='file\\d+.txt')#change the pattern as needed
lapply(files, function(x) {
                x1 <- read.table(x, header=TRUE)
                diag(cor(x1[,6:8], x1[,20:22], use = 'na.or.complete'))})
```

Comment: I just now create this code and results match perfect expect the output result is not in order   >>>>>                                                              directory <- "~/XXXX/XXXX /XXXX/DataXXX"
>    files <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
>    
>    correlations <- c()
>    
>    for (file in files) {
+       file_data <- read.csv(file, sep = ",");
+       complete_cases <- file_data[complete.cases(file_data),];
+      
+       correlations <- c(correlations, cor(complete_cases$v6, complete_cases$v20))

Comment: @user1894845  Not sure why it is not in order.  I tried on an example dataset and it was in order.  It is better to provide some example dataset.  Your code is different than the one I used.

Comment: i named the files like this x1 ....... x13      and the output  showed  x1, x10, x11, x12, x13, x2, x3 , x4 , x5, x6, x7, x8, x9.

Comment: @user1894845 Are those file names? i.e. `x1.txt`, `x2. txt`. etc...  If these are file names.  `files <- paste0('x', 1:13, '.txt'); lapply(files, function(x) {x1 <- read.table(x, header=TRUE); diag(cor(x1[,6:8], x1[,20:22], use= 'na.or.complete'))})`

Comment: I appreciate your help. it worked wonderfully. my file names are in order as well as the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute force version (with data generation included), it'll probably work for your purpose, a little more information about the structure of your data/task could help make this more efficient:

```
N <- 10
k <- 50

d <- data.frame(matrix(runif(N * k), ncol = k))

sapply(20:k, function(col) cor(d[,col - 14], d[,col]))
```

Edit: Question has been edited, I'm not sure if this is actually what you're after now.

Comment: thank you for supplying an answer for me.  its hard to explain my real task, but the example describes it.